# Rails performance plan for multi-user system where each user is store large amounts of data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of putting together a multi-user rails 3 app and before I got too far along I wanted to make sure there isn't a better way to be doing this...

Currently each table such as Contacts, Orders, Emails, etc has a user_id that it belongs to, but if I plan on having say 500 users each with 10,000 entries in each table is there a better option performance wise such as having user specific tables (user1_contacts, etc)?  And if so how can rails handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5,000,000 records in a table is not large. Foreign keys (belongs_to) and indexes are your friends here, which is good because they are both important parts of the drivetrain for relational databases (if in fact you are using relational). Beyond letting the database do what it's built to do, your only limitations are really going to be hardware. At the extreme end you will find hardware limitations that could cause you to evaluate partitioning schemes that help you divide the work, but you're a long way off from any of that.